# move_uploaded_file: not allowed to use tmp_name?

Tags: php, function

Question:

When you use the `move_uploaded_file` function, can you keep the name that was created in the `tmp_name`? or must you always change the name to something else?

If you can keep the name of the file that you are moving as the tmp_name, how must you pass in the argument? I tried the following code, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Please see the code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $target_file = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
    $upload_dir = "uploads";

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir."/".$tmp_file)){
        $message = "File uploaded successfully.";
    }else{
        $error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
        $message = $upload_errors[$error];
    }
}
```

When I pass the second argument in as **$upload_dir."/".$target_file** , there doesn't seem to be any issues, but when I pass it as **$upload_dir."/".$tmp_file** as shown in the codes above, it keeps giving me the following error:

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/C:\wamp\tmp\php1EA0.tmp): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\bb2\uploads.php on line 26
```

Comment: i know that the file is being moved, and I thought there shouldn't be an issue since I made a variable already: $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']. I imagined that I can use that variable as the second argument in the move_uploaded_file() function . Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try using ` $upload_dir."/".basename($tmp_file)`  $tmp_file is the full path to the file... you just want the name i'm assuming

Comment: Have you ever tried outputting the actual values of `$tmp_file` and `$upload_dir."/".$tmp_file`? I bet you'd get something like `uploads\C:\wamp...`.

Comment: ahh I seee. I kept thinking that it was giving me the basename already. Thank you thank you

Comment: Beware that tmp_name gets re-used, sometimes you will get filenames that have been used before. You need to double check that the destination path doesn't already exist before moving the upload, and if it does exist figure out a new path. See my answer for a short example implementation.

Comment: Pfft don't worry about downvotes. Your question was answered and anyone in future who uses the same wording as you will find your question and my answer. That's how the system works. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tmp_name` is not a file name, it's a full path to the file.

If you just want a random filename, I suggest code like this:

```
$dest = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
while (file_exists($dest)) {
  $dest = $upload_dir . '/' . substr(sha1(rand()), 0, 10);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], $dest);
```

`rand()` generates a random big number. `sha1()` uses that as the seed to create an even bigger random hex string, we don't want something that big so just grab the first 10 characters or so.

Comment: this was very helpful. if it's a fullname to the file, and the file that i'm uploading is a jpg, does it at least save into the temporary file as a jpg? or does it save as a tmp?

Comment: As @Orangepill  said, I imagined that I could just use the name that the basename of tmp_name created. If for some reason they change the jpg into some other file format, I assume basename($tmp_name) won't work

Comment: You can read the `$_FILES[]` array to see if the file name on the user's computer ended in "jpg" and you can see if their browser sent a mime type of "image/jpeg". However both of these are unreliable and sometimes they won't be there or will be incorrect (especially if someone is trying to hack your server... but also in non-malicious situations).

Comment: The only reliable way to check if something is a valid jpeg is to dry and draw it to the screen, or at least run it through an image processing tool of some kind. We usually resize all user-uploaded images to a reasonable size (assuming they might upload a 10 megapixel photo). If the resize fails, then you know it wasn't a jpg.

Comment: I can't seem to find where the file gets temporarily stored into. How can I find it? Also, if I put this on the server, where is this temporary file really going to before it gets moved? I haven't created any directory or path for these temporary files so I assume there must be a default path?

Comment: The temporary location is different for every server, the sysadmin/hosting company has to decide where they will be stored. Usually it's in a place where files get deleted every couple of days. PHP also deletes the files automatically, which might explain why you can't find them. Wamp is configured to store them in `C:\wamp\tmp`. You should use `$_FILES['tmp_name']` to find out where they are stored. That will work on every server, but you have to move them somewhere else immediately or else they will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error `$tmp_file` is an absolute path.

To get the filename from that path use `basename($tmp_file)`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
$tmp_file = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted you are passing the wrong argument the first argument for move_uploaded_file() has to be string filename try this

```
extract(pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']));


if(move_uploaded_file($filename, $upload_dir."/".$tmp_file)){
    $message = "File uploaded successfully.";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: I didn't have any problems with the first argument so far. Can you explain what you mean further?